# Name of the Marshall Hall paper in which he proved that the intersection of all subgroups of a fixed finite index is again finite index?

Tags: gr.group-theory, reference-request

can someone please tell me? I couldn't find a reference in the paper I was reading.

Comment: Note that this fact is only true in finitely generated groups.

Answer (score 6):

Subgroups of finite index in free groups. Canadian J.Math., 1:187–190, 1949.

Comment: This is not a result of Hall; Hall counted precisely the number of such subgroups.  Here are links to the paper:

http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v1/p187
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=28836
